# Disable Git integration in Visual Studio 2015 permanently

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs

I am using Android studio, where I always working with Git, but in Visual studio 2015 I am working with VFS. Problem is, Visual Studio always connect to my Git repo. instead to Team Fundation Server. When I reconnect to VFS and select one from my solutions, Visual Studio reconnect back to Git. So VFS is useless.

I tried to managed this problem with registry hack like here: 
[Question from: Matthew Kraus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304977/remove-git-mapping-in-visual-studio-2015) but no luck.

I want to use only VFS in Visual Studio, Git could be removed permanently.

Comment: Does VFS mean TFS(team foundation server)? Could you let us know which version of TFS are you using? Have you created git team project or TFVC team project?

Comment: I have found a reasonable solution to use TFS in VS2019 and Git from outside VS2019: stackoverflow.com/a/61658739/306074

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Problem solved using by [this](https://gist.github.com/hmemcpy/5bc6b5cc11050b502ca3):

Here's how to disable the package that is responsible for loading the Git source control support in Visual Studio. Use at your own risk!

1. Create a file called devenv.pkgundef and place it next to devenv.exe in you Visual Studio's Common7\IDE (you'll need elevation for this)
2. Add the following entries to the file:

   `[$RootKey$\Packages\{7fe30a77-37f9-4cf2-83dd-96b207028e1b}]
   [$RootKey$\SourceControlProviders\{11b8e6d7-c08b-4385-b321-321078cdd1f8}]`
3. Close VS if open, open a Developer command prompt, and type devenv /updateconfiguration
4. Start VS, and voilla - Git support no more!

To undo, delete the devenv.pkgundef file, and run devenv /updateconfiguration again.

Comment: While it works, it also cripples your manage connections. YMMV

Comment: Sometimes it throws error when you disconnect from TFS. It could be solved by restarting VS, or if you relog to your VS account.

Comment: It removed GIt, however, It kept throwing "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005):" on TFS after this. I recommend you do not try this on VS2015.

Comment: Usually restart of Visual Studio fixed it.