# Unbind Source Control for Solution or Project VS 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2017 to unbind a solution or project from source control?  I can only find answers to this question for older versions which suggest going into **File > Source Control** however it appears the **Source Control** option has been removed in this version.

For older versions:

[2010,2008,2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181375(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Git has nothing to do with Visual Studio. You don't *bind* the project with git. If the folder contains a `.git` folder, it *is* a git repository

Comment: The question speaks for itself. Because the project is no longer going to be in source control.  Why are you downvoting something you don't understand?

Comment: For example, if you want to send a project folder to a client, you can use [git archive](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) to create a zip with the files without the `.git` subfolder. You can also use `git clone --depth=1` to only the latest version of a repo.

Comment: In my case, I came here because I attempted to add a new project to Team Services and the IDE assumed I wanted a GIT repro, no questions or confirmation asked.

Comment: no, this would make life enjoyable and the goal of visual studio and TFS is to make life miserable

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In VS2017 (checked in versions 15.8.9 & 15.9.10) and VS2019 (16.5.4) and VS2022 (17.1.3), goto:

Tools / Options / Source Control / Plug-in Selection

In combo-box "Current source control plug-in:", change to "None" and click OK.

The project will close; just reopen it and that's all...

[image]

*To reach the Plug-in Selection section in Options, you can also use the search box; just type "Plug-in" and click in "Source control -> Plug-in Selection". In combo-box "Current source control plug-in:", change to "None" and click OK.*

[image]

Comment: Will it unbind the currently opened project/Solution or all the projects/Solutions?

Answer (score 12):

just remove all .git base files from project root folder and sub folder, after that restart solution and project you will get git free project

Answer (score 6):

In Visual Studio 2017, open a connected project or solution then select:

1. **File**
2. **Source Control**
3. **Advanced**
4. **Change Source Control**
5. Click **Unbind** on the project or solution of your choice.

Comment: In VS 15.7.2 there is no Source Control item on the File menu, at least on my setup. Do you have a screen shot you can add?

Comment: Worked for me.  I'm using VS Professional 2017, version 15.9.6

Comment: Note that VS 2017 will only show the source control option under the file menu if the loaded solution is using a TFVC repository. In the case of the asked question, it would not show up because it is using a git repository.

Comment: I know this post is about VS 2017 but apparently VS 2022 has no File -> Source Control option.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the only way to do this is manually removing files.  This answer worked for me:

[Remove .git* files and folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35517310/8174844)

Comment: Because Visual Studio has nothing to do with git. You didn't "unbind" the project from source control. You deleted the repository itself. The `.git` folder *is* the repository.

Comment: BTW why? This is an extremely bad idea. If you encountered a problem with git, solve it. Git isn't broken. Without it you *will* lose files and changes. The way the universe works, by next Tuesday

Comment: Thanks.  I accidentally added my project to git, when I meant to add it to TFS.

Comment: it seems the git team thinks they are more important than the other source control providers